# OpenGL 3.2 trouble setting up matrices

Tags: c++, opengl, matrix, glsl, glm-math

I am using GLM to manage my matrices, but I am running in to some problems that make no sense to me. When I set the projection matrix to anything other than an identity matrix, I can't see the square I am trying to draw. If it is an identity it will work. Something similiar happens with my view matrix. If I try and translate past -1 or +1 the square will dissapear, otherwise it seems to have no effects.

There are no OpenGL errors, GLSL linker/compiler errors, and glGetUniformLocation returns a valid location. Also the shader program is correctly being used.

Also I have tested the shader to see if it is getting the correct values passed to each of the matrices (by changing the color of the square if the value is correct).

Here's how I set up the projection matrix:

```
projectionMatrix = glm::perspective(60.0f, (float)windowWidth / (float)windowHeight, 0.1f, 100.0f);
```

And here's my draw function:

```
void OpenGLContext::render(void) {  
glViewport(0, 0, windowWidth, windowHeight); // Set the viewport size to fill the window  
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT); // Clear required buffers  

//Set up matrices
viewMatrix  = glm::translate(glm::mat4(1.0f), glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, -5.0f));
modelMatrix = glm::scale(glm::mat4(1.0f), glm::vec3(.5f));  

shader->bind();

int projectionMatrixLocation = glGetUniformLocation(shader->id(), "projectionMatrix");
int viewMatrixLocation = glGetUniformLocation(shader->id(), "viewMatrix");
int modelMatrixLocation = glGetUniformLocation(shader->id(), "modelMatrix");

glUniformMatrix4fv(projectionMatrixLocation, 1, GL_FALSE, &projectionMatrix[0][0]);
glUniformMatrix4fv(viewMatrixLocation, 1, GL_FALSE, &viewMatrix[0][0]);
glUniformMatrix4fv(modelMatrixLocation, 1, GL_FALSE, &modelMatrix[0][0]);

glBindVertexArray(vaoID[0]);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);   
glBindVertexArray(0);

shader->unbind();

SwapBuffers(hdc);
```

}

Here's the shader.vert

```
#version 150 core

uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;
uniform mat4 viewMatrix;
uniform mat4 modelMatrix;

in vec3 in_Position;
in vec3 in_Color;
out vec3 pass_Color;

void main(void)
{
    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * viewMatrix * modelMatrix * vec4(in_Position, 1.0);
    pass_Color = in_Color;
}
```

Here's shader.frag

```
#version 150 core

uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;
uniform mat4 viewMatrix;
uniform mat4 modelMatrix;

in vec3 pass_Color;
out vec4 out_Color;

void main(void)
{
    out_Color = vec4(pass_Color, 1.0);
}
```

Sorry forgot about what i'm drawing:

```
void OpenGLContext::createSquare(void)
{
float* vertices = new float[18];

vertices[0] = -0.5; vertices[1] = -0.5; vertices[2] = 0.0; // Bottom left corner  
vertices[3] = -0.5; vertices[4] = 0.5; vertices[5] = 0.0; // Top left corner  
vertices[6] = 0.5; vertices[7] = 0.5; vertices[8] = 0.0; // Top Right corner  

vertices[9] = 0.5; vertices[10] = -0.5; vertices[11] = 0.0; // Bottom right corner  
vertices[12] = -0.5; vertices[13] = -0.5; vertices[14] = 0.0; // Bottom left corner  
vertices[15] = 0.5; vertices[16] = 0.5; vertices[17] = 0.0; // Top Right corner  

glGenVertexArrays(1, &vaoID[0]);
glBindVertexArray(vaoID[0]);

glGenBuffers(1, vboID);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboID[0]);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 18 * sizeof(GLfloat), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glVertexAttribPointer((GLuint) 0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);

glEnableVertexAttribArray(0); // Disable our Vertex Array Object  
glBindVertexArray(0);

delete [] vertices;
}
```

Setting my matrices like this results in nothing being drawn on the screen. Like I said if I set the projection and view matrices to an identity it will work. The scaling on the modelMatrix seems to always work as well.

Comment: It's kind of hard to answer this question without knowing what you're actually trying to render.

Comment: Can you describe how you're changing the projection matrix, what you expect to happen, and what is actually happening? Pictures would help enormously.

Comment: Wow I have no Idea how but when i went to go take a screenshot to show you guys it just started working correctly? I'm not complaining just confused haha. I must have fixed it accidentally when I was debugging?

Comment: You should mark the question as anwered.

Answer (score 0):

There is no attribute on position 1 (`in_Color`). If you just left it out of this question, then the problem are the locations, which you are not defining in the shaders. I've never actually tested it without the location part, but I *think* it's necessary, at least for multiple values: you should use e.g. `layout(location = 0) in in_Position`.

Comment: A stride of 0 specifies tightly packed data and is absolutely fine.

Comment: What? I always thought 0 would mean each component was size 0, while sizeof(float) * 3 would mean they were three floats wide

Comment: No, `0` is a special value. See [the documentation](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glVertexAttribPointer.xhtml).